# cv.h: file not found opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm running this code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0; }
```

But it isn't working for me because it shows this error on my screen when I write cmake . in terminal:

> cv.h: file not found.

Could anyone help me? It was working one month ago.

Answer (score 3):

you have linking problem, try this out;

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` filename.cpp -o filename
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! it's working now. :D Do you know how to fix to run with Makelist?

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( rubicSolver )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable( main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

Comment: @eiki it's exactly what I have in my CMakeLists file but it doesn't work. any idea why?

Comment: ah ok I found out my problem: I had installed version 3.0 and was following a tutorial for version 2...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the linker properties in case of Visual studio.
For Makefile you need to make sure that the opencv_dir is set correctly.